# How to get the index of space before specific string?

Tags: java, regex, string

I have below string

```
String = "Test1 Test2 Test3 Test4 Test5 Test6  15min"
```

I want to get the index of character space before string "min"

There is a method like  `String.lastIndexOf(" ")` but could not find any thing related?

**EDIT:-**

Basically want to find last space before the first min

Comment: what did the method return for you?

Comment: It's not clear what regular expressions have to do with this... and what if there are multiple "min" occurrences? Do you want to find the last space before the first min?

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes you are correct

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First get the position of the string that you want to get the space before, then use that position to get the closest previous position of space

```
int idx1 = str.indexOf("min");
int lastSpace = str.lastIndexOf(" ", idx1);
```

Comment: It would be better if you'd add some *explanation* here along with the code. (And use indentation for the code rather than tags, to give nicer formatting.)

Comment: @controlAltDel perfect

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with regex - search for a space followed by non-space characters followed by `min`, like this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s\\S*min");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("Test1 Test2 Test3 Test4 Test5 Test6 15min");
// Check all occurrences
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.print("Start index: " + matcher.start());
}
```

This prints 36, the index of the last space character prior to `15min`.

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/nLU3oS)

Answer (score 0):

you can put your code in a html div with the id named string:

```
var data = $('#string').text();
var arr = data.split(' ');
$("#string").html("<span>"+arr[0] + "</span></br>" + arr[1]+"/"+arr[2]);
```

When you split this string ---> Test1 Test2 Test3 Test4 Test5 Test6  15min on /

```
var myString = "Test1 Test2 Test3 Test4 Test5 Test6  15min";
var arr = myString.split(' ');
```

you'll get an array of size 3

```
arr[0] --> test1
arr[1] --> test2
arr[2] --> text3
....
```